# Application processes causing CPU spikes using IIS 7

Tags: c#, .net, iis, windows-server-2012

I am addressing a problem with an application in production that is causing the CPU to spike and pin. It seems to gradually increase CPU usage until it hits 100 percent (usually within 24-36 hours) and I have been unable to find the exact code that is causing this issue. Using IIS 7 I identified the application pool that is causing the problem. The memory usage is normal, but there are usually a couple of worker processes that are frozen. Over the course of the past week I kept track of these frozen processes and there are no patterns that would help narrow down the issue. The pages that are frozen are always different and the user IPs are always different. Is there an application pool setting other than recycling the application pool that I can use to kill these frozen worker processes after X time?

Comment: Does recycling the app pool correct your problem?  it is possible to change the recycle time to something other than the default of 29 hours.

Comment: It does fix the issue, however; my concern is that it will kill any active sessions. Even with the CPU pinned at 80% there is no performance degradation for users on the application. I would much rather kill the offending processes rather than recycle the application pool every 4 hours or so and potentially cause issues with other active users.

Comment: You could try enabling [worker process pinging](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc725836), possibly with tightened timeouts. This may not help if the worker processes are actually still responsive and just eating an unfair share of resources, but it's worth a try. Of course, the best long-term solution is to find and fix the problem, but that's a bit more work, involving taking a dump of the worker processes and running it through a debugger (windbg can find the most active threads with `!runaway`). This has a bit of learning curve.

Comment: Speaking of dumps, you can also use [`procdump`](https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/dd996900) to automatically initiate a dump (and terminate the process with `-k` if you're so inclined) explicitly after its CPU or memory use reaches a threshold. For this to work, it must be the case that the worker processes individually exceed some threshold, not just that there are too many of them.